# How to see how much music do I have in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music

The new iTunes version has brought some changes. And I just realized that it won't show anymore how much music do I have.

It used to say the size and the total play time at the bottom of the window, but it's gone now. Can I ripristinate the indicator? Or what's the easiest way to check my music library size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bring back those details at the bottom of the screen by clicking **Show Status Bar** in the **View** menu, or pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings, then General, then About and it should list how many songs, videos, photos etc. that you have.